# Why is code introduced in API 29 working on an emulator running API 26?

Tags: java, android, api, gradle, emulation

I am using [BiometricManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricManager#canAuthenticate(int)) (Introduced in Api 29) in a project with a minSdkVersion of 26.

To my surprise, the project is compiling and running, I would have expected this to throw an error at buildtime. Am I missing something? Will this cause issues on release?

Gradle:

```
    defaultConfig {
 
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
```

Class:

```
       import androidx.biometric.BiometricManager;
       import androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt;

      
public BiometricPromptClass(Activity activity) {
    this.context = activity.getBaseContext();
    this.activity = activity;
}

public int getDeviceBiometricStatus(){
    return getBiometricManager().canAuthenticate(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_WEAK);
}

public boolean CheckIfCanAuthenticate() {
    if (getDeviceBiometricStatus() == BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    } else {
        failureCode = getDeviceBiometricStatus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It work because ```minSdkVersion```is 26. It may not work as it should, but work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using BiometricManager

No, you are not... at least, not the one that you linked to. You linked to `android.hardware.biometrics.BiometricsManager`. Your code uses `androidx.biometrics.BiometricsManager`. Those are not the same class. The Jetpack (`androidx`) edition will have code that tries to support older devices gracefully.

Comment: Good spot, Yep, thats the answer -  wrong import. 

Such a simple thing to miss!